# react.js with webpack Resource blocked due to MIME type mismatch

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

Developing a react app with webpack, in my app.js router when i specify the route to be /foo the component renders normally but when i specify a route as /foo/bar i get the following error
"The resource from “http://localhost:9000/foo/bar/bundle.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)"

**App.js**

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/api/login" component={Login} /> //gives error
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} /> //renders normally
                        <Route component={Error} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index'),
    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module:{
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/react']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:[
                    {loader: 'style-loader'},
                    {loader: 'css-loader'}
                ]               
            },]
    },
    devServer:{
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        port: 9000,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    plugins:[
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "src/index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Are you using `express` as a back end at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and solved it by adding `publicPath: '/dist/'` in the `output` option of `module.exports` in `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Now getting `Cannot GET /xx/yy`. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score -3):

Try to change the content-type to 'text/javasscript'.

```
content-type: "text\javasscript"
```

Comment: The type of what?

Comment: More context?..