# react: Routing: How to create multi-level routing?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'd like to create a route with multiple levels (`<Route path="/hello/world" element={<a>hello world</a>} />`)

Versions:

- react: 18.1
- react-router-dom: 6.3.0

**One level works**

The following is a simple class containing a route with only one level (`/hello`):

```
const App = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/hello" element={<a>hello</a>} />
      </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Everything works fine, here.

**Two levels don't work**

But if I introduce another level into the path (`/hello/world`):

```
const App = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/hello/world" element={<a>hello world</a>} />
      </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

the browser stays white an the console shows the error

```
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/hello/bundle.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).world
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

## Other Parts of the Code

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>Management Console</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## What I've found

- [react-js-with-webpack-resource-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59364518/react-js-with-webpack-resource-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch) seems to be the same question. However,

  1. The given accepted answer didn't solve the problem (Error message `Cannot GET /hello/world` with 4 console errors)
  2. The other answer did not help at all.
- [react-router-dom-6-unable-to-route-dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70669684/react-router-dom-6-unable-to-route-dynamically) might have the same problem
- 

Comment: I have tried creating a code sandbox demo with multi level routing and it was working as expected.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-forked-skexbk?file=/src/App.js
Particularly you can check /apple/some and it was working.

Comment: If you are working on a demo project would you like to share Github repo or can you share your package.json file?

Comment: @BhaveshDaswani Thank you very much for the quick mock up! So my problem must be related to some settings, I guess. Unfortunately I can't share the code :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48568560/6702598) solved the problem:

> Add `<base href="/" />` within the `head` tags of you `index.html` file.

If anyone has any idea on how this works, feel free to edit this wiki.